# Minimizing space around shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Was wondering if there is an automated way to re-position shapes to minimize the space between them. Besides manually trying to guess the optimal configuration.

I am trying to achieve some layouts like the following
[image]

Comment: The feature you are describing is called "nesting" and Illustrator does not have a native way to do this. It requires special plugin software that you can buy separately.

Comment: Manual placing is easy in Inkscape. There the bounding box contains the stroke and snap to bounding box is possible. Let objects have a stroke and drag them to lean against each other. Select all, remove the stroke => objects have equal gaps between them